# meaning of "catch up with someone"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "caught up with" mean in the following?

> KSL Sports **caught up with** two fans as they brought things to the statue to pay tribute to the passing of Kobe Bryant

The Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary has the following definition and example for "catch up with." Do they apply to the above sentence?

> to meet with (someone)

> I've got to go. I'll **catch up with** you later.

Answer (score 0):

The usage sounds weird to me, but it is being used in the "to meet with (someone)" sense.

Generally, "catch up with" is informal and implies an existing familiarity. You catch up with your friends or family, but generally wouldn't catch up with a stranger. It also implies that the meeting is to discuss how they've been doing. I like the definition given by Google/the OED better:

> Talk to someone whom one has not seen for some time in order to find out what they have been doing.

I suspect the writer didn't want to use a more formal phrase like "spoke with" or "interviewed" because the article was about people's emotional reactions to Bryant's death. You also hear "chatted with" used in similar situations.

Comment: I would find 'caught up with' to be quite normal in a US or UK informal news context to mean 'encountered at an event and interviewed'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It wouldn't strike me as odd if it were, eg, a celebrity giving an interview, but maybe it's totally normal and I just haven't noticed it before. Hm!

Comment: @Kaia Are you a native speaker? Maybe this is a new usage?

Comment: @Apollyon I am a native speaker (West coast USA)

Comment: Not just celebrities. NBC News caught up with a Wisconsinite in Ukraine, NBC News caught up with Santa Charles Graves at the Gaylord Resort in Maryland as he visited with a group of children, NBC News caught up with a woman claiming to be a neighbor of Bouhlel's who said he was "frightening" and "not normal." NBC News caught up with a family in which the parents had been having trouble spending time with their kids because they were too indulged with technology.

Comment: Quite a few British examples also.

Comment: @Apollyon Of course she is a native speaker. You can tell by the fact there are zero mistakes in the answer. caught up with here is just spoke to.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an euphemism for verb "talk" or "communicate". Maybe it's like a daily usage or smth

Comment: Hello Petro,  It's best not to guess the answer.  If you know an answer and can explain it well then please write an answer.  But it seems in this answer you are saying "I don't know what it means, but I can guess from context."